# Is there a way to do einsum in Python with boolean logic to optimize it?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

Okay, so basically i'm working on some sort of image blending thing, and i have a function that will blend every image in the given array according to some specified weight, like in the code below:

```
#Weighting Function
def weight_sym(n):
    n = int(n/2)
    r = range(n,-n,-1)
    val = [math.exp(-(2*x/n)**2) for x in r]
    val = val/np.sum(val)
    return val

#Blending Function
def blend(imgs):
    num = len(imgs)
    Weight = weight_sym(num)
    P = np.einsum("ijkl,i->jkl", imgs, Weight)
    
    return P.astype(np.uint8)
```

Note : `imgs` is an array that holds multiple images in the form of pixel arrays, the shape is `(n,1080,1920,3)` where `n` is the amount of images, `1080 and 1920` is actual image dimension, and `3` is the rgb value.

Ok, but unfortunately for large amount of images, the code seems to slow down really badly, and because 75% of all images is just black background, i was wondering, can i only do `einsum` calculation only if the pixel value is actually changing at least once in every images. (Perhaps utilizing `np.allclose()` and use the boolean output (?))

What i mean by that is i want to reduce the amount of calculation needed by ignoring pixel that doesn't change value at all in every image. So my question is, is it actually possible to do that and get a better performance? if so, can you provide an example?

Comment: That `einsum` can also be written as `np.sum(imgs * Weight[:,None,None,None]), axis=0)`.  That said, it isn't clear what you want to skip, whether it's certain images or certain pixels from all images, or selected pixels from selected images.  Keep in mind that in `numpy` actions like masking and testing are about as expensive as multiplication.  Use `numba` (other 'c' coding) if you want fine level control.

Comment: i want to skip certain pixel from all images, is that possible?

Comment: Just select the pixels you want from the 4d `windows` array.  It will be fastest if you can use slices, eg. `windows[:, i:j, k:l, :]` for 4 values.

Comment: Basically any selection of pixels is done before passing to `einsum`.  Some `ufunc` (which `einsum` is not) have a `where` parameter  which is used with `out` to use a subset of that elements.  But that is most often used when certain values shouldn't be used in a calculation (such as 0's in divide).

Comment: @hpaulj so, how exactly do i do that?? :/